# Tangential Motion of an Object Attached by a Radial Elastic String

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

A toy car travels in a horizontal circle of radius *2a*, kept on track by a radial elastic string of unstretched length *a*. The period of rotation is *T*. When the car is speeded up the string stretches until the car is moving in a circle of radius *3a*. Assuming that the string obeys Hooke's law, the period of rotation is now:

- A: Unaltered
- B: $ \frac{3}{4} T $
- C: $ \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} T $
- D: $ \frac{3^{2}}{4^{2}} T $
- E: $ \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}} T $

This question A46 from an old UK 1972 A level physics question book (ISBN: 0713123141).

The answer according to the actual book is C, but how on earth do you get there?

Comment: Shouldn't the unstretched length $2a$? Otherwise, I don't see how it can keep the toy in a circle of radius $2a$.

Comment: The angular velocity of the car means it is pulling on the centre of the circle. Hence this causes the stretching of the string. As the car speeds up the pulling force increases meaning the string is stretched longer. Circular motion requires a centripetal force pulling inwards which in this case is the stretched string. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: If the string is not stretched I don't see how it can pull the car to the center. But, let's wait and maybe somebody else would have a different interpretation.

Comment: [my crude diagram](https://i.imgur.com/OG83qkE.png)

Comment: The string is being stretched - it has natural length $a$ and at its initial angular momentum the string is stretched to $2a$, there is therefore a centripital force of $F=ka$

Comment: Yes, your diagram make it clear to me. I'll think about it and see if I can answer.

Comment: As mentioned by Bill Watts, express both forces in terms of the period (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) and isolate the desired expresion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got $F1$ and $F2$ right.  Now use the fact that $F=\frac{m\ v^2}{r}$ for circular motion to find the two velocities.  The from the circumference and velocity, you can find the ratio of the periods.

Comment: I have attempted this however it doesn't seem to get the answer the book says - can you see any mistakes in [this working](https://i.imgur.com/EdbT7Tq.png) ?

Comment: You are squaring your v twice.

Comment: that was it, got the answer now thanks